# memory efficiency creating multidimensional array in steps

Tags: java, performance, multidimensional-array

I have a shapes that can have multiple contours and segments.
I mostly store the info like `someArray[theContour][theSegment]`.
I want to store the bounding of each segment, which is an array of 4 elements in 2d and 6 in 3d.
So it will be like: `bounding[theContour][theSegment][4]`.

At the moment I only create the required parts when the method get's called:

```
 public void calculateBounding(int contour, int segment) {

        if (boundingContourSegment == null) {
            boundingContourSegment = new float[nOfContours][][];
        }
        if (boundingContourSegment[contour] == null) {
            boundingContourSegment[contour] = new float[nOfSegments[contour]][];
        }
        if (boundingContourSegment[contour][segment] == null) {
            boundingContourSegment[contour][segment] = new float[size];
        }
```

My question is, is this bad for performance? Is it better to just create the whole array in one time (or at least all segments of the specific contour)?

Comment: isn't that a bad practice for modeling? i once try to model a game with multidimension arrays to increase performance, but after a while i came back to OOP because of the mess in code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you will call your calculateBounding method more often. It might be a problem if your segments will be created over a longer time. It could be a problem of caching etc, that means that your segments will be spread over the memory. In highly optimized environments this is a bottleneck, so it depends on you application context, otherwise create it at once.